# What is this type of lock called?

Tags: bathroom, doors, toilet, lock

My bathroom lock is broken and I am looking to buy a replacement, but I don't know what its called.

Here is a photo of the broken one and a working one from the toilet.

[image]

Would anyone know the search terms I would use to find a similar one to order?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the point of posting two pictures? ... no way to tell from the picture which one is broken ... are you looking to replace the one on the right or the one on the left?

Comment: do a google image search on one of the locks ... you may get a useful hit .... can't do it with a picture of two locks

Comment: Could you also add a picture of the latch?

Comment: it's a prIvacy latch-set but you'll probably want a more specific term.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-keyed locking door knob is generally known as a "privacy knob."

That one has a surrounding plate and an exposed switch. When all the hardware is together like that there is a chance it's a mortise lock, but you can confirm this by looking the side of the door and seeing if all the parts are combined.

[Example of similar hardware](https://www.houseofantiquehardware.com/antique-mortise-door-hardware-brass-privacy-set?utm_source) that looks different but might work the same way.